# Using ASP.NET MVC without an ORM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, datatable, datareader

In my ASP MVC application I'm using standard SQL (rather that Linq to SQL or other ORM) to query my database.

I would like to pass the database results to my view and iterate over the results in my view. But I'm not sure how to do this.  Every example I've seen passes some string or uses L2S.  I would like to pass something like nested Hashtables, but the only thing I can think of is to pass an SqlDataReader object to the view, but this sounds like a really bad idea.

How would I go about displaying my database results from a standard SQL query to my view?  I would really like use Linq or other ORM, but requirements dictate we don't (don't ask me why, I don't understand).  I'm doing this in VB.  I'll try by best to convert any C# examples provided.

Comment: Its not good to fulfill a requirment you "don't understand", I suggest you go back to who ever is imposing the requirement and get an expliantion.

Comment: Anthony, in some enterprises there are architects who make these decisions, and it isn't always a good idea to question them. They decide, you code.

Comment: @DOK: Any architect worth paying would rather coders understand their designs.  If thats not so where you are its time to dust off your CV.

Comment: AnthonyWJones: I think DOK was being ironic ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could create simple classes for the data you want to transfer and then populate a List of objects in your controller from a data reader manually, and then pass this to your View - e.g. (C# but this should be easy to convert)

```
// open your connection / datareader etc.

List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

while(dataReader.Read())
{
 Customer c = new Customer();
 c.Id = dataReader.GetInt32(0);
 c.Name = dataReader.GetString(1);
 // etc (you might want to use string indexers instead of ints for the get methods)

 customers.Add(c);
}

// close and dispose your datareader / connection etc as usual

return View("List", customers);
```

Comment: In other words, roll your own ORM :).

Answer (score 8):

MVC is about separation of concerns. Passing SqlDataReaders, DataTables, or whatever class that resides in the System.Data namespace to a view is not a good idea. You need to define a model which might talk to the database, and a controller which will pass this model to the view. If your company policy says don't use an ORM then maybe classic WebForms are better suited to your scenario than the MVC pattern.

Comment: I have to agree. Mvc forces the separation of the various layers, which is the reason for implementing it. However I have already seen various implementations where the purpose of the technology is ignored. It is unfortunately a reality of the industry we work in.

Comment: Better have model ask business logic to talk to the database. Models are not supposed to be that intelligent.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Rashack. This article explains it in some detail.[link text](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/14/2623.aspx)

In a nutshell, here's how to do it using DataTable and DataReader:

```
private DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection connection
             = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";

        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader =
            command.ExecuteReader
                (CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Then, you can read that DataTable into an entity object that you pass around.

I think you'll find this can yield much better performance than using Linq or an ORM.

Answer (score 5):

Try using DataTables - DataTable can load data from IDataReader... (I think the method's called Load)

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own [Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object) classes and populate instances of them using ADO.Net code.  These DTO classes would be simple [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)-style classes that just contained property get/set accessors, no methods.  Using POCO objects is arguably preferable to DataSets/DataTables as they are lightweight (no superfluous state) and are more intuitive to work with from an object-oriented perspective.

Comment: Can't see how using your own DTOs differs much from using an ORM, surely if there was a sensible argument to avoid existing ORM tech such as LINQ (and I'm not conviced there is) wouldn't this restriction also apply to a home grown one?

Comment: By LINQ, I assume you mean LINQ to SQL (LINQ by itself it a set of language extensions that add query-based logic to CLR languages, not an ORM)?  You haven't explained why your requirements prohibited you from using an ORM like LINQ to SQL.  Commercial ORMs contain a rich set of features for dealing with the object-relational impedance mismatch.  LINQ to SQL tracks changes to object state and converts queries composed using LINQ into native SQL.  Populating and returning DTOs from the results of a query executed through ADO.NET is just a different method of transfer from returning datasets.